# Odd Angular/Bootstrap Dropdown Behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've got an application requiring a series of dropdowns.  The functionality requires me to be able to switch between normal dropdown behavior and multi-select behavior.

I have made slight modifications to the `ui.boostrap.dropdown` from the Angular Directives for Bootstrap (see **[Dropdown](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown)**).  Everything works well, except for a gray bar after clicking (looks like the `:hover` css stays active after clicking) when in Multiselect mode.

When I toggle off then back on, the highlight goes away, as if the hover event has somehow completed.

**Process:**

1. Open the dropdown
2. Click Multiselect
3. Move the mouse and Multiselect stays highlighted, as if the ":focus" tag is not removed.

**Visually:**
The mouse is over 345 in this image, Multiselect should ***not*** be highlighted.

[image: Multiselection]

Angular HTML for dropdown:

```
<div ng-controller="DropdownCompanyController as vm">
    <div class="btn-group u-front_dropdown-wide" dropdown is-open="vm.isopen">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
            {{ vm.selected }} <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" ng-click="vm.checkMultiSelect($event)">
            <li ng-repeat="company in vm.companies"
                ng-class="{ selected : company.selected }">
                <a href="#" ng-click="vm.event.select(company)">{{ company.name }}</a>
            </li>

            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="ng-scope" ng-class="{selected : vm.multi.select }">
                <a href="#"
                    ng-click="vm.event.multiselect()"
                    ng-class="{ multi: vm.multi.select }">Multiselect</a>
                <button
                    ng-hide="!vm.multi.select"
                    ng-class="{ multi_button: vm.multi.select }"
                    ng-click="vm.event.close_dropdown($event)">Close</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the event where the click on an element is handled:

```
vm.event = {};
vm.event.select = function(company) {
    if (!vm.multi.select) {
        clearCompanies(false);
        company.selected = true;
        vm.selected = company.name;
        vm.isopen = false;
    } else {
        if (company.name !== vm.defaultCompany) {
            company.selected = !company.selected;
            vm.selected = vm.multi.title + countCompanies();
        }
    }
};
```

Link to **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ML83oFaNI8a0KAzY0Xcj?p=preview)**.

I have had no luck tracking this down and my instinct is that the issue is in the CSS, but it's standard bootstrap CSS.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just dont want any item to have the highlight then in your own custom app.css file override the focus state with white:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Without doing a custom bootstrap build just add the hover following the focus to to keep the grey highlight:

```
 .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
      background-color: lightgray;
    }
```

Comment: +1: This is absolutely a thought I had, but I do want the highlighting when focused, just not after the click event.

Comment: @rfornal, so isn't that just about breaking out the override of the hover as well in your app.css file?  see above.

Comment: Tested this on the Plunker ... I'm sure I tried something like this; I guess the operative word is "LIKE".  Thanks for setting me straight.